# Tag [license] or [licensing]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I've noticed that we have two tags which essentially seem to mean the same thing: [[license]](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/license) and [[licensing]](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licensing). Which one should we keep? Or is there maybe a subtle distinction which might make it worth to keep both?

Answer (score 7):

This subject space is better expressed as [licensing](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licensing). Question about a specific license might pick a narrower 'license' tag, but when folks are talking about licensing concepts in general, it wont be a good fit. You don't need both tags. You should have one tag and text completion will guide them to the right fit.

<kbd>l</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> → <kbd>licensing</kbd>

Comment: I also support [licensing], but for a different reason: it's spelt the same way in both US and UK English. Unlike, say, _license_ (US spelling for both noun and verb; UK spelling for verb only) vs _licence_ (UK spelling for noun).

Comment: So are you suggesting burninating [tag:license]?

Answer (score 4):

To me they seem to be used for the same thing. Even if there were a subtle nuance this doesn't seem reflected in usage. Maybe redirect one to the other?

Comment: You don't really need a redirect here. There should be one tag, and text completion will guide user towards the one. Tag synonyms (redirects) were designed when there were two completely *different* words to describe a topic. That's not the case here.

Comment: @RobertCartaino But if for some reason the text completion doesn't work (like it frequently doesn't on my phone) it would still be good to have the synonyms so that high rep users don't accidentally make new tags (or use the less common version).